# Why don't we have an EVM integration library written in C++?

Tags: wallets, evm, cpp-ethereum, library

We have web3.js for JavaScript, web3j for Java and NEthereum for Unity/.NET.

I want to develop with Unreal Engine (C++) a game that runs on Polygon, but there's no integration library in C++.

Should I bother trying to make a basic implementation of NEthereum/web3.js written in C++? Or are there any specific reasons of why C++ is not a preferred language?

Also, I guess that in the future we're going to have more desktop blockchain games; if that's the case, we're also going to need a 'Desktop Metamask', or a convenient wallet that can be easily integrated to interact with desktop applications.

For this situation in particular, option A would be handling wallets inside the game (unsafe), option B would be developing an easily verifiable and open source C++ wallet (so we can create an UI/interface for it in Unreal) and transactions would be signed outside the game. Option C would be implementing WalletConnect in C++

**Would developing this bring real value to the ecosystem?** Or should I build a similar approach to 'Etherlinker' where they use a localserver for the EVM integration

Comment: It is just that there wasn't enough interest. From time to time someone will ask about C++ and sometimes they will get an answer, for example https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/103686. There's Aleth a C++ client https://github.com/ethereum/aleth, but the project isn't very active. If you are willing to write such library for C++ you should consider asking the Ethereum Foundation a grant.

Comment: IMHO option A would be handling wallets inside the game (unsafe), is not unsafe, if users just use this for tokens within the game. There Option B, you have other options (although not hardened) https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.UI.Desktop or you have https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum-Explorer-Wallet-Template-Blazor examples to get started. WalletConnect will require a C++ implementation anyway, which takes you to point A (less the signing).  Now another option will be to interop with the Delphi implementation, I don't know how suitable will that be in your environment.

Comment: Yet another option for Unreal could be https://github.com/nxrighthere/UnrealCLR, although if all your code is in C++ I don't know how good the interop will be.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. 
@Ismael I think the interest will grow over time if adoption keeps growing. Yes, I've checked the Aleth, but as you mentioned its only a client, sadly it's not a library.

Comment: @JuanBlanco I tried implementing UnrealCLR, but it's basically a dependency nightmare to deal with because of Nuget packages. We will use NEthereum as a localserver for a short-term solution and keep analyzing on developing a native library for C++.